# Error in proof of definite integral of periodic function

Tags: definite-integrals, solution-verification

For a periodic function $f(x)$ with period $T$,
we have $$\int_0^{nT} f(x)\,dx =n\int_0^T f(x) \, dx$$

Let $$I=\int_0^{nT} f(x)\,dx$$

I tried to prove this by taking $$y=\frac{x}{n}$$
$$dx=n\,dy$$
When $$x=0,y=0$$
$$x=nT,y=T$$
So the integral
$$I=\int_0^T f(ny)\cdot n\,dy$$
$$=\int_0^T f(ny)\,d(ny)$$
Replacing the dummy variable,
$$I=\int_0^T f(x)\,dx$$

Where have I gone wrong? Also I have not used the fact that $f(x)$ is periodic.

Comment: Replacing the variable $n y$ is just going back to $x$, so you must get back the original limits of integration. Intuitively, $f(n x)\neq f(x)$ so you are not using periodicity.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you gone wrong where you write $udy=duy$ because limits are of $y$ not of $duy$